# Displaying a gray scale image to picture box in MFC using SetDIBitsToDevice

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, mfc

I use the following code to display OpenCV's IplImage. It works well for the RGB image.But for the gray image (only one channel), the image is upside down (inverted).

```
    if( m_img && m_img->depth == IPL_DEPTH_8U )
    {
        uchar buffer[sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + 1024];
        BITMAPINFO* bmi = (BITMAPINFO*)buffer;
        int bmp_w = m_img->width, bmp_h = m_img->height;
        FillBitmapInfo( bmi, bmp_w, bmp_h, Bpp(), m_img->origin );
        from_x = MIN( MAX( from_x, 0 ), bmp_w - 1 );
        from_y = MIN( MAX( from_y, 0 ), bmp_h - 1 );
        int sw = MAX( MIN( bmp_w - from_x, w ), 0 );
        int sh = MAX( MIN( bmp_h - from_y, h ), 0 );
        SetDIBitsToDevice(
            dc, x, y, sw, sh, from_x, from_y, from_y, sh,
            m_img->imageData + from_y*m_img->widthStep,
            bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS );
    }
```

I looked at the function in link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162974%28VS.85%29.aspx) and showed that lpvBits is for RGB color. How can I modify for gray image?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use GDI+

1. Load the colored Bitmap
2. Create a ColorMatrix with 30% Red 59% Green
   11% Blue
3. Create an ImageAttributes
4. Set the ColorMatricx into the ImageAttributes
5. Create a new bitmap
6. Use DrawImage with the ImageAtributes and draw the colored bitmap into the new bitmap.

There is a nuch of C# code samples, but the GDI+ interface in C+ is nearly identical.